Roblox Server-Script to teleport all players to a random seat not working
Here's the code
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
local char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local spawns = workspace:WaitForChild("TruckTweenPart1").MainTruck.Spawns:GetChildren()
local randomIndex = math.random(1, #spawns)
local targetCFrame = spawns[randomIndex].CFrame
char.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = targetCFrame
print(char.Name)
end)

The script doesn't do anything when I join and it doesn't print any errors in the output

You don't give much info, but I assume the script never runs (is in the wrong place)

Please include where your script is and if the character's name prints. Like @Weetz said, it could be how the script never runs so we would need that information to help determine that.
